# True/ False to strength my knowledge in calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Q1) For a continuous function $f$ whose domain is all real numbers, if $f'(p)$ is    undefined, then $x = p$ could be a local maximum or minimum of $f$.

I say that at corners it could be maxima or minima but if we are taking the derivative it will be considered undefined and the maxima and minima points has to be zero. (False)

Q2) For a function $f$ whose domain is all real numbers, if $f''(p) = 0$, then the graph of $f$ has an inflection point at $x = p$.

I would say it is true, I saw some examples with this definition occurs but I am not sure. ( True)

Q3) For a function $f$ whose domain is all real numbers, if $f'(p)=0$, then $f(x)$ has a local minimum or local maximum at $x = p$.

It is true for sure, but does it only have to be local maxima or minima ? because sometimes it crosses the $x$ axis while not having maxima or minima. Am I right ? (True)

Q4) For a function $f$ whose domain is all real numbers, a local maximum of $f$ only occurs at a point where $f'(x)=0$.

That has the same issue as the first question and I would say true. (True)

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

Q1) $f(x) = |x|$

Q2) $f(x) = x^4$

Q3) $f(x) = x^3$

Q4) $f(x) = -|x|$

at $x = 0$.

Let me know what your T/F answers are after you think about these examples.

Comment: 1) False because it will form a corner 2) False, it will be 12x^2 so it will not have an inflection point 3) True, 3x^2 will form  maximum 4) I don't know

Comment: I feel that I am mixing things up

Comment: 1) Look at the definition of a local minimum. Not having a corner isn't a requirement. 2) Your answer is correct, but you should be able to explain why $f''(x) = 12x^2$ implies that $f$ doesn't have an inflection point at $x = 0$. 3) The question asked if $f(x)$ has a local minimum not if $f'(x)$ has a local minimum. 4) Does $f(x) = -|x|$ have a local maximum at $x = 0$? Is the derivative of $-|x|$ defined at $x = 0$?

Comment: 1) I am confused, I know that a corner could be a local minima but is it the same case when you are taking the derivative ?

Comment: A function can have a local minimum/maximum at a corner point. However, a function is not differentiable at a corner point.

Comment: 2) I know the reason // 3) Yeah, so the answer will be still true but my explanation was wrong.